# How to print a JSON array from Javascript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to print a single value from a JSON array and I can't seem to make it work.

Json code is like this format and has about 1000 members with 10 parameters each
 {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 2,
  },
I can retrieve the value correcly with console.log(list[1].A) but can't seem to make it print in HTML

It might be a newbie question but none of the solution I test seem to work.
So how can I print a  specific member of JSON array in HTML?

```
JavaScript

var fs = require('fs');

var list = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('csvjson.json', 'utf8'));

document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = list[1].A;


HTML

<div id='insert'>
</div>
<script src='jsfile.js'>
</script>
```

Comment: `fs.readFileSync` is only meaningful in Node, but rendering HTML is done client-side, right..? (Check your browser console for errors to debug)

Comment: Would seem there is a misunderstanding between client side and server side programming.

Comment: Can you include sample of the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it all depends on the JSON data format you received and how you will access the variable.
Do not always trust the console, sometimes you can see the values ​​of the elements in the console while in reality you need a getter function to have this value.
This is especially the case when you work on google maps projects.
In short, the code you put should work if the JSON format is the same as my code.
That is objects inside a array.
I  advise you to review your JSON format and check how to recover the value.
I hope this will help you.

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var objet1 = [{name: "Sallo",lastname: "hi"},{name: "Salou",lastname: "Everyone"}];

//Here objets json in array
div1.innerHTML = objet1[0].name;
```

```html
<div class="inner" id="div1">
</div>
```